# Conflicting setter definition for field name starting with set

Tags: java, jackson, objectmapper, jackson-databind

We have a pojo generated from yml which has @JsonProperty defined on the getter. This is based on maven plugin for openapi. For one such yml, we have a field settlementType. We can't change the name as this is the field to be sent to the vendor in the rest api call. When using jackson's ObjectMapper to deserializa the object, we get the following error -

> Conflicting setter definitions for property "settlementType":
> settlementType(1 param) vs setSettlementType(1 param).

I tried for a mixin class.

```
public class SettlementTypeMixin {
@JsonProperty("settlementType"
String settlementType;

@JsonIgnore
public void setSettlementType(String settlementType) {
   this.settlementType = settelementType;
}
}
```

I added the mixin to the mapper using addMixinAnnotations method. But I don't see any change in the behavior.

I also tried setting the fieldVisibility, getterVisibility, setterVisibility and CreatorVisibilities as well. There are other types as well which the yml needs and at the end I have to enable the visibility for all the types mentioned below.

I am not able to get the object mapped using jackson. Please let me know if there is a way out for this.

Comment: Ah, welcome to the fun of Jackon's "split properties" feature. Can you please include the generated class that's giving you trouble?

Comment: You need to share the generated class.